# PowerShell to list logs files on recurse folder then create zip monthly using 7zip on it's directory

Tags: powershell

Im trying to create script to list logs then compress it monthly and put it on the same directory.
We have many logs subfolder inside C:\TestLogs\
Example Script that i have

```
# set folder path
  $log_path = "C:\TestLogs\"
  $7zip_path = "C:\7z\7za.exe"

  # set min age of files
  $max_days = "-30"

  # get the current date
  $curr_date = Get-Date

  # determine how far back we go based on current date
  $zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)

  # filter files
  Get-ChildItem $log_path -Recurse   | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt 
  $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)} |

   ForEach {
  $Zip =  $log_path + "{0:MMM}_{0:yyyy}.zip" -f $_.LastWriteTime
  & $7zip_path u -tzip $Zip $_.FullName |Out-Null
   }
```

And the result is it creating Mar_2018.zip etc only in C:\TestLogs\ 
how to make the zip created inside of the subfolder like C:\TestLogs\logbakcup\Mar_2018.zip or 
C:\TestLogs\Runtime log\April_2017.zip or C:\TestLogs\logbackup\January\January_2017.zip

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know syntax of 7zip util, but you could try to use native powershell command Compress-Archive. Something like this:

```
#set folder path
$log_path = "C:\TestLogs\"
$7zip_path = "C:\7z\7za.exe"

#set min age of files
$max_days = "-30"

#get the current date
$curr_date = Get-Date

#determine how far back we go based on current date
$zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)

#filter files
[array]$folders = Get-ChildItem $log_path | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)}

ForEach  ($subfolder in $folders) {
    $subfolderLastWriteTime = Get-Date $subfolder.LastWriteTime -Format 'dd.MM.yyyy'
    $DestPath = $subfolder.Fullname + '\' + $subfolderLastWriteTime
    Compress-Archive -Path $subfolder.FullName -DestinationPath "$DestPath.zip"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i got this error Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Object reference not set to an instan
ce of an object."  and The term 'Compress-Archive' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Chec
k the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: What version of powershell do you use? It looks like "Compress-Archive" appeared in version 5. About date error: Try to execute simple script, like: Get-Date -Format 'dd.MM.yyyy'. Does an error with date still appear?

Comment: PS C:\> Get-Date -Format 'dd.MM.yyyy'
28.09.2018 Date seems showing
PS C:> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Version 2 ?
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1

Comment: Yep, you have powershell v2. Its strange, but I cant reproduce you error with Get-Date, even with powershell v2. I can suggest you to use $DestPath variable with 7zip util, it might help. Try to experiment.